# Adding capabilities in an OCP BuildConfig

Tags: docker, build, openshift, podman

Is there a way to add capabilities in a `BuildConfig`?  I have a Docker strategy, but need to add capabilities like `--cap-add=CHECKPOINT_RESTORE`

My current `BuildConfig`

```
kind: BuildConfig
metadata:
  name: modresorts-build
  labels:
    app: modresorts-build
spec:
  source:
    type: Git
    git:
      uri: https://github.com/bpaskin/...
  strategy:
    type: Docker
    dockerStrategy:
      dockerfilePath: Dockerfile
      from:
        kind: ImageStreamTag
        namespace: demo
        name: liberty:liberty
  output:
    to:
      kind: ImageStreamTag
      name: modresorts-app:latest
  triggers:
     - type: ImageChange
```

For reference I would do the following on a Linux command line:

```
podman build -t modresorts --cap-add=CHECKPOINT_RESTORE --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --cap-add=SETPCAP --security-opt seccomp=unconfined .
```

Answer (score 0):

the SCC (security context) needs to be updated with the capabilities necessary.  https://github.com/ibmruntimes/InstantOnStartupGuide/blob/main/YAMLs/ocp/scc-cap-cr-4.13.yaml